# How to convert other source maps to Obf ( Eg Navteq,garmin,tom Tom)

Tags: maps, osmdroid

I am looking for a solution to create a better OSMAND map for a region , as existing OSM maps are not complete.

If I get a map in Navteq/Garmin/Tom Tom format, will I be able to convert it to Osmand OBF format and replace in Osmand ?

There seems to be less references to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect Navteq/Garmin/Tom Tom would give maps in shapefile format, and OSM can take data from shapefiles per http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Obtaining_OSM_data_from_shapefiles

HOWEVER... Navteq, Garmin, and Tom Tom are commercial organizations which value their data; I would be very surprised if their license would allow you to give it to OSM for free use.  Furthermore, I expect that OSM would not allow you to give it to them.  So I would be very surprised if this approach worked.